# USB-HDD restoring

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning

Got an HDD uninitialized, can't access it. Checked through diskpart - disk 1 appears connected but shows 0 bytes, I can select disk but there's no partitions on it. Diskmgmt also shows disk as uninitialized, No data. Other utilities like EaseUS Partition Recovery, Wondershare Recoverit or CrystalDisk can't even see this disk. Event log shows event #51 IO error hardware fault. So is this really hardware fault, because diskpart sees disk actually. There's some important data on disk so I don't wanna risk trying to reinit it. Any suggests?

Comment: Restore the important data from backup.

Comment: This is, obviously, not possible. If it would, I wouldn't even ask the question.

Comment: Remove the actual HDD from its enclosure and attach directly. Alternatively use an enclosure/bridge you know is good. Alternatively test the current enclosure with a disk you know is good. This is to catch a possibility the problem is because of the enclosure. What are the results? ([edit] the question).

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to connect disk through SATA because USB port is located directly on it

Comment: The question will probably be closed as a duplicate of this one: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/q/241817/432690) If recovery software cannot see the disk then most likely the only options are: (1) hiring a professional, (2) accepting the loss. Good luck.

Comment: Like Kamil said, you won't be able to save this drive yourself without putting the data at risk. You'll have to use professional data recovery services and it will be expensive. Let this be a lesson and come up with a reliable backup strategy.